# Если в div добавляется class, добавлять class в соседний div

Tags: javascript, jquery

В коде, представленном ниже, есть `class="jq-selectbox jqselect"` при определенном действии пользователя к этому классу добавляется `changed` в итоге получается: `class="jq-selectbox jqselect changed"`.

Как сделать, что бы (одновременно с добавлением `changed`) в соседний `div` с `class="pay_line_a"` добавлялся `active` и в итоге получалось `class="pay_line_a active"`, а при отсутствии `changed`, так же убирался и `active`?

```
<div class="sec">
  <div class="jq-selectbox jqselect">111</div>
  <div class="pay_line_a">222</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем? *(8 символов нужно...)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.jq-selectbox.jqselect ~ .pay_line_a {
  color: green;
}
.jq-selectbox.jqselect.changed ~ .pay_line_a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sec">
  <div class="jq-selectbox jqselect">111</div>
  <div>insert</div>
  <div class="pay_line_a">222</div>
</div>
<div class="sec">
  <div class="jq-selectbox jqselect changed">333</div>
  <div>insert</div>
  <div class="pay_line_a">444</div>
</div>
<div class="sec">
  <div class="jq-selectbox jqselect">555</div>
  <div>insert</div>
  <div class="pay_line_a">666</div>
</div>
```